# Customisable <li>'s in a list not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change one of the li elements to be red, another li element hyperlinked in a different colour with an underline rollover effect, and another li element hyperlinked in the standard colour but with an underline rollover effect that does not change the colour.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Appreciate the help.

```css
ul.standard-list{
 padding:0px 0 50px 00000;
 margin:0;
 text-align:left;
 color:#333;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family:verdana,arial,"Times New Roman", Times, serif,georgia,serif,helvetica;
 font-size:20px;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 line-height:28px;
}
ul.standard-list a:link{
 color:#008CBA;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.standard-list a:visited{
 color:#008CBA;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.standard-list a:hover{
 color:#008CBA;
 text-decoration:underline;
}
ul.standard-list li{
 list-style-type: none;
 line-height:28px;
}
ul.standard-list li:before{
    /* Unicode bullet symbol */
    content: '\2022';
    /* Bullet color */
    color: #008CBA;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.standard-list.no-list-decoration{
 color:red;
}
.standard-list.link-2 a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="standard-list">
          <li><a href="http://google.co.uk">linked, underlined in different colour with underline rollover effect</a></li>
          <li class="no-list-decoration">red</li>
          <li class="link-2"><a href="http://google.co.uk">linked, underlined rollover effect but same colour as normal list style</a></li>
          <li>four</li>
          <li>five</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: define different class and call where you want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing space in your css:

```
.standard-list.no-list-decoration{
```

change to

```
.standard-list .no-list-decoration{
```

or

```
ul.standard-list .no-list-decoration{
```

And the same with

```
.standard-list.link-2 a:hover{
```

change to

```
.standard-list .link-2 a:hover{
```

Answer (score 3):

Define different classes to get different rollver effect behaviours for different `li` tags, **underlined in different colour with underline rollover effect** (.link-1) & **underlined rollover effect but same colour as normal list style** (.link-2)
and style them respectively

```
ul.standard-list .link-1 a:hover{
    color:red;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.standard-list .link-2 a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```css
ul.standard-list{
 padding:0px 0 50px 00000;
 margin:0;
 text-align:left;
 color:#333;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family:verdana,arial,"Times New Roman", Times, serif,georgia,serif,helvetica;
 font-size:20px;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 line-height:28px;
}


ul.standard-list a:link{
 color:#008CBA;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.standard-list a:visited{
 color:#008CBA;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.standard-list .link-1 a:hover{
 color:red;
 text-decoration:underline;
}
ul.standard-list li{
 list-style-type: none;
 line-height:28px;
}
ul.standard-list li:before{
    /* Unicode bullet symbol */
    content: '\2022';
    /* Bullet color */
    color: #008CBA;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.standard-list .no-list-decoration{
 color:red;
}
.standard-list .link-2 a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="standard-list">
          <li class="link-1"><a href="http://google.co.uk">linked, underlined in different colour with underline rollover effect</a></li>
          <li class="no-list-decoration">red</li>
          <li class="link-2"><a href="http://google.co.uk">linked, underlined rollover effect but same colour as normal list style</a></li>
          <li>four</li>
          <li>five</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Red was not showing because you had no space between the 2 classes

```css
ul.standard-list{
 padding:0px 0 50px 00000;
 margin:0;
 text-align:left;
 color:#333;
 font-weight:100;
 font-family:verdana,arial,"Times New Roman", Times, serif,georgia,serif,helvetica;
 font-size:20px;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 line-height:28px;
}
ul.standard-list a:link{
 color:#008CBA;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.standard-list a:visited{
 color:#008CBA;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.standard-list a:hover{
 color:#008CBA;
 text-decoration:underline;
}
ul.standard-list li{
 list-style-type: none;
 line-height:28px;
}
ul.standard-list li:before{
    /* Unicode bullet symbol */
    content: '\2022';
    /* Bullet color */
    color: #008CBA;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.standard-list .no-list-decoration{
 color:red;
}
.standard-list .link-2 a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="standard-list">
          <li><a href="http://google.co.uk">linked, underlined in different colour with underline rollover effect</a></li>
          <li class="no-list-decoration">red</li>
          <li class="link-2"><a href="http://google.co.uk">linked, underlined rollover effect but same colour as normal list style</a></li>
          <li>four</li>
          <li>five</li>
    </ul>
```